# notice board hover while click on

Tags: notice

i just wants idea..how to get through it.,.

Please visit the site http://www.gumtree.com.au/ .On the right side of the homepage, in one column, there area a number of sticky notes like notice areas. Each of these notice areas has a number of radio buttons and when you hover over one of the radio buttons, the content of the notice area changes. I want to know if there is a JQuery plugin or if it is possible by programming. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are divs with images, not radio buttons and yes, this is completely possible by programming using jQuery with CSS and images. [Here is an example](http://caroufredsel.frebsite.nl) of a jQuery plugin that does pretty much exactly the same thing.

Comment: I wasn't asking for that..i was talking about the sticky note like notice area..

Comment: If I'm looking at the same area (http://o7.no/UpDBqi), it seems to me that this is exactly what you're talking about. However, instead of showing several slides at once, you'd show one slide and a circle representing the number of slides. Note that "slides" can just be divs that contain styled text.